# NestJS - Email validation not working properly

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs

I have an email like: test@test.com, it works properly

But if I have test+test@test.com, validation rejects it. Not a valid email

Dto:

```
@Exclude()
export class GetUserDto {
    @Expose()
    id!: number

    @Expose()
    @IsEmail()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty({
        example: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        description: 'Username',
    })
    username: string
}
```

NestJs uses validator.js under the hood for the validations. And the [validator demo](https://codepen.io/oshihirii/pen/vjxamY) allows the plus sign. What gives?

I would like to avoid writing custom regex for email :(

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign is valid for an email address, e.g. johndoe+imvalid@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the + in an email is referred to as an alias. In developement I often use this for testing, it allows you to have multiple accounts with the same email address. The server recognizes it as unique but it simply boils down to the same email address wrt your email server.

Eg: email.true@gmail.com, email.true+1@gmail.com, email.true+also@gmail.com -- are all the "same" email addresses while still being unique.